# Remove the Button from the LinearLayout

Tags: android

I am creating a `CheckBox` list and `Button` from `ArrayList<Integer>`, which I am getting as response from the server, programmatically. For updating purpose I am trying to delete the `CheckBox` list as well as the `Button` before I add the new one. With the current state the `Button` is not being deleted I noticed that when the `ArrayList` becomes empty the `Button` was not deleted.

How can I delete  the `Button` in the case the table is empty since too there is some cases where the table becomes empty?

```
    @Override
    public void onAsyncTaskFinished(ArrayList<Integer> result) {

        remove_elements();
        createCheckboxList(result);


    }

private void remove_elements() {
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
        for (int i : items) {
            CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(i);
            if (ch != null) {
                parent.removeView(ch);
            } else {
                System.out.println("The checkbox is null");
            }    
        }

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(1);
        if (btn != null) {
            parent.removeView(btn);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The button is null");
        }

    }

    private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
        final ArrayList<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
            cb.setId(items.get(i));
            ll.addView(cb);

        }
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
        btn.setText("submit");
        btn.setId(1);
        ll.addView(btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only create the button if items.size() > 0

```
if (items.size() > 0){
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
        btn.setText("submit");
        btn.setId(1);
        ll.addView(btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}
    }
```

Comment: It works thanks but I cant understand why should the items size be greater than 0 to delete it?

Comment: You aren't deleting the button, you are creating the button if items.size() > 0, is not the same, the result is the same, but is more efficient.

Comment: yep but my problem was to delete the button and when I added the if statment it is being deleted now also I dont understand cohesion(the relation) between creating and delteing in this context.

Comment: Comment the method remove_elements() and you can test if this is unnecessary. You call this method before a creation, you can call it after the creation or use a if for know if items size > 0